# Adding two GalleryViews in one activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I would like to add two gallery view to my app. To be clear with my question as it shows in the image below. I would like to add another **horizontal scroll view below the image view that will also display images and function exactly as the one above**.

[image]

Here is the code that I've come up with so far. It's the same **example** as the **developer samples**. Just some minor changes to it.

```
public class Gallery2DemoActivity extends Activity {
private Gallery gallery,gallery1;
private ImageView imgView;

private Integer[] Imgid = {
        R.drawable.a_1, R.drawable.a_2, R.drawable.a_3, R.drawable.a_4, R.drawable.a_5, R.drawable.a_6, R.drawable.a_7
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.examplegallery);
    gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));

    gallery1 = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.examplegallery1);
    gallery1.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));

    imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);    
    imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[0]);


     gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]); 
        }
    });

}

public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {
    int GalItemBg;
    private Context cont;

    public AddImgAdp(Context c) {
        cont = c;
        TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
        GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        typArray.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Imgid.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(cont);

        imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]);
        imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(110, 100));
        imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);

        return imgView;
    }
}
```

}

Below is my **XML file**. Which is pretty straight forward and simple.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<Gallery
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/examplegallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
<Gallery
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/examplegallery1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can't I set two gallery Views to one AddImg adapter ?

Where am I going wrong ? The Second Horizontal Scroll View is not showing up.

How can I work around this problem ?

Comment: What problem are you facing right now..? are you getting any Exception, any Unexpected behavior, tell us what happens if you run it.

Comment: @AdilSoomro The second horizontal view in the bottom is not showing up. I've edited the question thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You need `android:layout_weight="1"` in your `ImageView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks that the problem is in your layout implementation. Try setting **android:layout_weight="1"** on the image view. I think that will solve the issue. Modified layout is provided below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Gallery
                android:id="@+id/examplegallery"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <Gallery
                android:id="@+id/examplegallery1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your absolutely right ! that solved the issue. Could you tell me what is supposed to mean ?

Comment: android:layout_weight Indicates how much of the extra space in the LinearLayout will be allocated to the view associated with these LayoutParams. Specify 0 if the view should not be stretched. Otherwise the extra pixels will be pro-rated among all views whose weight is greater than 0.